# Trying to measure point density along a line

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.3, point, density

I have a dataset that consists of animal sightings along a road and I want to calculate the density of points (sightings) along that road.  My primary goal is to measure sighting hot spots, but I also want to subsequently look at the habitat characteristics associated with these hotspots.  Kernel and point density do not seem appropriate b/c I only have measurements along this road (a line) I have no measurements of occurrences at locations away from this line. I'm using ArcGIS 10.3  Suggestions?

Comment: I don't have arcgis but I suspect you might get more help if you could share your dataset or a small portion of it for someone to analyze and reproduce to provide an answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. First use [Generate Network Spatial Weights](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/generate-network-spatial-weights.htm) in ArcGIS. This tool will generate a matrix file from network that you will use it in other tools
2. Use the matrix file in [Hotspot Analysis](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-statistics-toolbox/hot-spot-analysis.htm) tool . with this method you use the hotspot analysis alonge the path. 
   You can use the Matrix file for other analysis.

Answer (score 1):

I just found this. Maybe other people still are as well.
A different option, that might work better (better for me) is discussed here:
https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/product/mapping/using-graduated-lines-to-show-the-number-of-accidents-along-road-segments/

Your run the Spatial Join Tool to basically count how many points are near each segment of your line set. In the questioner's case you would need to break your road up into a number of linked segments.

You can set the search radius. It was able to handle a large dataset quite well, where an attempt at a density/heat map of my points just crashed each time.